# Name the digraph of these transformation subsemigroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, finite-semigroups

I am trying to track down the name of this structure and some references.

You take all members of the transformation semigroup on $n$ elements, $T_n$.

For two members $x, y\in T_n$: if $x$ is in the subsemigroup generated by $y$ then you put an arrow from $y$ to $x$. You would read this as $x$ is in the subsemigroup generated by $y$.

What is the name of this digraph? References would be great.

Here is the graph for $T_{3}$.
[image: T3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the partial order under containment on the monogenic (generated by 1 element) subsemigroups of the full transformation semigroup $T_n$. A digraph is just a binary relation and a partial order is a special type of binary relation.

This is not a property which is specific to transformation semigroups (your definition didn't involve transformation semigroups), but to semigroups in general.

You could calculate this partial order using [GAP](http://www.gap-system.org) for some small values of $n$.

Comment: Does GAP have a Schrier-Sims type data structure for working with transformation semigroups?

Comment: The short answer is: yes. In the [Semigroups](http://www-groups.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/~jamesm/semigroups.php) package, which is a GAP 4.7.2 package (this should be released any day now).

Comment: @ChadBrewbaker does my answer answer your question?

Comment: Got a link to a paper describing this generalized schrier-sims data structure?

Comment: Just to add that GAP 4.7.2 is now released, see http://www.gap-system.org/